# Method setSQLLogger deprecated - Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

I am in the process of upgrading an application from Symfony 5.4 to Symfony 6.0. Along the way, I had to upgrade some doctrine libraries.

We are currently using setSQLLogger(null) to avoid having SQL logging enabled. By using the newer version of Doctrine, I am getting a warning:

*The Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::setSQLLogger method is deprecated (Use {@see setMiddlewares()} and {@see \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\Middleware} instead.).*

I could not figure out how can I replace setSQLLogger(null) with setMiddlewares so I could disable the SQL logging.

Did anyone have this issue and managed to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I replaced this code:

```
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

With:

```
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setMiddlewares([new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\Middleware(new \Psr\Log\NullLogger())]);
```

This puts the NullLogger as the only middleware.

Comment: Wont this replace all middlewres possibly breaking doctrine if its using more than just the logger?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a [middleware](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.4.x/src/Logging/Middleware.php) in order to accept the `NullLogger`, then use it along with `setMiddlewares` method.

So from symfony standpoint, you can do something like

```
# configuration.yaml // or whatever name you have
services:
  doctrine.logging.middleware.null: // or whatever name you prefer
    class: Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\Middleware
      autowire: false
      arguments:
        - #FQCN or service id of NullLogger
```

Then you can inject it where you were using `setLogger` and replace that method call with `setMiddlewares`.

I didn't tried it myself, as we're running on older version, but I'm pretty confident this should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the package `roave/psr-container-doctrine` you can register new middleware in your autoload config using the associated key [middlewares](https://github.com/Roave/psr-container-doctrine/blob/4.2.x/example/full-config.php)

Then you create a new service which build an instance of `Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\Middleware`.

Example building the service with Monolog logger:

```php
class DoctrineMiddlewareLoggerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, ?array $options = null)
    {

        $logger = new Logger('doctrine');
        $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('logs/doctrine.log', Logger::DEBUG));
        $logger->pushProcessor(new PsrLogMessageProcessor(null, true));
        return new Middleware($logger);
    }
}
```

Wire the service with your factory:

```php
return [
            'factories' => [
                'doctrine.middleware.logger' => DoctrineMiddlewareLoggerFactory::class,
```

Configure your middleware in the configuration key:

```php
 'configuration'=>[
            'orm_default'=>[
                'middlewares'=>[
                    'doctrine.middleware.logger'
                ]
            ]
        ],
```